# Workaround to use lightningstylesheets="true" AND renderAs = "pdf" in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I really need to use lightningStyleSheets="true" in my component (styled otherwise it just doesn't look as nice). (standardcontroller="Lead"). Where I'm stuck is that I need to take this page and save it as a pdf to the lead record, which seems to requre using renderas="pdf". However it seems these 2 cannot be used together-- it just displays Salesforce Internal Error... on the page. I am trying to think of some sort of workaround. Is there any way to upload this page to the Lead record without using renderas="pdf"? What if I load the page in a lightning component, then load that component in a new vf page- would that work? Just trying to think of anything.. really need to make this work :) Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. Sometimes it takes a little bit for someone to get an answer to you. Being impatient will not speed up that process.

Comment: Sure- sorry about that